# What are $n$ that are such that $x^{n^4} + x^{n^3} + x^{n^2} + x^n + 1$ is divisible by $x^4 + x^3 + x^2+ x+1$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, complex-numbers

To be honest, I would love to specify my progress but I basically have no idea how to solve it. However, I was given a hint (which I couldn’t find out how to use) that to solve it we should use some knowledge about complex numbers.

Note: $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Hint: If $\omega$ is a root of $\sum_{k=0}^4 x^k$, then $\omega^5 = 1$ and  $\sum_{k=0}^4 \omega^{n^k} = \sum_{k=0}^4 \omega^{{\rm mod}(n^k,5)}$.

Comment: Hint: You need $n$ to be a generator of $\Bbb Z_5^*$

Comment: If I was attacking this problem, the very first thing that I would do is consider the 6 cases of $x \in \{2,3\}$ and $n \in \{2,3,4\}.$  This is such an obvious investigatory step that I am disappointed that you didn't include this exploration as part of your original query.  The other responses show insight.  In math, if no inspiration occurs in the first 15 minutes, then it is time for 20-30 minutes of perspiration.